# Batch File Issue with Program Files 86 Java Call

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm getting a 'The system cannot find the path specified' error message when running a short batch that correctly echos the LAW_JAVA_HOME variable and set the new variable. Even when I run this from the command line CMD - and include the variable - it returns the same error.

```
@ ECHO OFF
if not defined LAW_JAVA_BIN (
    set LAW_JAVA_BIN=%LAW_JAVA_HOME%\bin
)
%LAW_JAVA_BIN%\java.exe -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar 
%LAENVDIR%\java\bin\managegrid.jar %*
```

The path issue is related to this path with should be PF86 - C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Comment: Use doublequotes to protect spaces in your strings.

Answer (score 1):

My comment as an answer:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Defined LAW_JAVA_HOME Exit /B
If Not Defined LAENVDIR Exit /B
If Not Defined LAW_JAVA_BIN Set "LAW_JAVA_BIN=%LAW_JAVA_HOME%\bin"
"%LAW_JAVA_BIN%\java.exe" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "%LAENVDIR%\java\bin\managegrid.jar" %*
```